# Collect metrics for each individual recipent on Amazon SES

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, email, html-email, boto3

I'm using Amazon's Simple Email Service to send transactional emails. To do so, I created a Python class that uses the AWS SDK for Python, Boto3.

One of the parameters of this class, recipients, represents a list of recipients who will receive the emails. I created a configuration set with the "ses: from-domain" auto-tag and established that the collected metrics will be sent to the CloudWatch service.

With this setting, I can check the number of recipients who opened the emails, clicked on the contained links, or faced rendering failure. However, these values ​​are presented in aggregate form.

I would like to know how:

1.Use the configuration set to collect metrics for each individual recipient (email address);
2.Integrate that configuration into the method I'm using to send emails or the HTML code that constitutes the email. Since I currently use the auto-tag feature, it only needs the configSetName on my code.

Method for sending emails:

```
def send_email(self, subject, charset="UTF-8"):
        """
        """
        # Create a new SES resource and specify a region.
        client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=self._aws_region)

        # Try to send the email.
        try:
            #Provide the contents of the email.
            response = client.send_email(
                Destination={
                    'ToAddresses': self._recipient,
                },
                Message={
                    'Body': {
                        'Html': {
                            'Charset': charset,
                            'Data': self._html_content.getvalue(),
                        },
                    },
                    'Subject': {
                        'Charset': charset,
                        'Data': subject,
                    },
                },
                Source=self.sender,
                # If you are not using a configuration set, comment or delete the
                # following line
                ConfigurationSetName="test",
            )
        # Display an error if something goes wrong. 
        except ClientError as e:
            print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
        else:
            print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
            print(response['ResponseMetadata']['RequestId'])
```

Comment: No, I did not :/